# Ds160 USA, if I work as independent contractor with US company

Tags: visas, usa

I'm working full time job remotely with  a company in USA, they invited me to go there for tourism and to discuss our projects, I won't be working there and won't get paid for the time, but they will sponsor my full trip, and I live in Egypt. My questions are:
Should I add the company as my current employer? And about the funding, should I say that that employer in the US will pay?

Thank you

Comment: Certainly if they're paying for the trip you should say that they're paying for the trip.  Whether you should list them as an employer is a more delicate question to which I do not know the answer.  I suspect that it would be best to represent yourself as self employed and them as your client, but I am by no means certain of that.

Comment: Are they your employer? Are you getting a payslip and all the social and labor rights of an employee as per the Egyptian law? (I'm not familiar with what specifically those would be)

Comment: I think that is the question, am I an employee or just a contractor. I work full time remotely but I handle my own taxes and insurance in my country.

Comment: I would describe the people you work for in the US as your _client_ and very definitely not your employer.

Comment: I agree with you jack, I'm just confused what to add under current employer, should it be awlf employed or freelancer.